# How to update update existing custom post type with register_post_type permanently?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to perform quick rewrite slug update for my custom post type on the fly. So I use code like in my theme's functions.php:

```
$no = get_post_type_object($pt_slug);
$no -> rewrite['with_front'] = false;
$no -> rewrite['slug'] = $slug;
register_post_type($pt_slug, $no );
```

Which is hooked to 'init' `add_action('init', 'check_post_type_rewrite_url');`

There is large code so I write only issue part in here.

`register_post_type` returns object with updated slug. I understand it means my custom post type was updated, but it was not. Existing post type still has its old rewrite slug. Should I add something special for rewrite rules to save changes and make it work? Or there is specific way to register/update post types with rewrite slug so it worked?

Comment: Did you flushed your rewrite rules by visiting the permalinks settings page?

Comment: No, and that actually helped, OMG. I read an article which said that there is no need to flush rewrite rules anymore, it was an issue in WP 3.0. I simply added flush_rewrite_rules() after the update and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Sorry I missed yesterday that flush_rewrite_rules() performs temporary rewrite rules update on the fly. Rewrite slug of custom post type is not being rewriten permanently. So it is not a solution which I look for. What else could I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way you solved the issue - by using [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) - is technically correct but not recommended. As stated in the doc:

> This function is useful when used with custom post types as it allows for automatic flushing of the WordPress rewrite rules (usually needs to be done manually for new custom post types). **However, this is an expensive operation so it should only be used when absolutely necessary**.

So you shouldn't keep your `flush_rewrite_rules()` call in your init hook, as it will regenerate all the rewrite rules at every page load, which is really badly ressource consuming.

Usually it's enough to just visit the **Permalinks Settings page** to flush the rules - so if you change again your CPT slug in the future, just visit the page once.

If your slug could change dynamically, then you can make use of `flush_rewrite_rules()`, but you need to use it *carefully* - it shouldn't be called on every page load, but could be used by a periodic cron job, or on plugin activation / deactivation, depends of the case.

Comment: I understand that, thank you. I'm going to make a plugin for developers which could connect pages with custom post types, so if page slug is changed then post type rewrite slug is also changed. That would simplify living for many developers who need such functionality.

Comment: Sorry I missed yesterday that flush_rewrite_rules() performs temporary rewrite rules update. Rewrite slug of custom post type is not being rewriten permanently. So it is not a solution which I look for. What else could I do wrong?

Comment: @Nick Late answer, but `flush_rewrite_rules` does flush permanently the rules. So if the CPT slug change, it is probably because you still have and old definition of the slug in the `register_post_type` configuration that conflict with.

Comment: I already solved that issue and now work on plugin which could help who needs such functionality. I hope I finish that this week, it will do couple of other things as well.